# Cordova / Ionic framework ( Android ) - splash screen is out of ratio

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on a ionic cordova app i created a PNG 2208x2208px spalshscreen then created splashscreens using:

```
$ ionic resources
```

The splashscreens are generated but the problem is on my phone the splashscreen is streched/mashed like out of ratio.

My config.xml has this inside:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="14+"/>
  <preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect"/>
  <preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded"/>      
<platform name="android">
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
      </platform>
```

This scares me since there could be tons of other mobile phones where my splashscreen gets streched too, i guess :/

I can't understand why the splashscreen looks so bad, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend you to read about [9 patch splash screens](http://www.tidev.io/2014/02/12/android-splash-screens-using-9-patch-images/). It is the way Google recommends do it:

You also have a generator: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: thank you man, solved using this https://github.com/junkoro/make-9patched-splash-ionic